# Why does my desktop background does not change after executing Python script?

Tags: python, osascript

I followed [this](https://youtu.be/VLNcnROUTb8?t=376) tutorial for changing the background on my macOS Monterey 12.5. When I run the Python script my background ist not changing but I also don't get an error message.

In `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Automation` I added the terminal in which I execute the script for being able to access `Finder`.

**Code to change background:**

```py
cmd = "osascript -e 'tell application \"Finder\" to set desktop picture to POSIX file \"" + filename + "\"'"
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Does it work if you call osascript from a shell?

Comment: It works, thanks! How/or should I even give you kudos in my answer? @Stuart

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I executed the Python script from iTerm and **NOT** from the standard Terminal.

Thanks to @Stuart from the comments in the post (how can I link people from comments in answers or should I even do this?).